# Adding Vertical Field Manager in blackberry tree view

Tags: blackberry, treeview

Hello I am new to Blackberry , Can any one tell me that how to add Vertical Field Manager in to Tree View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeField` is not designed for this. It is not a `Manager`, so you can't add any child fields to it. Similar to `ListField` the `TreeField` is a way to represent on UI a potentially large data structure without eating too much RAM (since in this case there is the only UI object - the `TreeField`).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, But my question was that in tree field we can add child as addChildNode.(int parent , Object coockie); , Then can't we pass Vertical Field manager as Object parameter in it ?